# Garbage Collector generations not incrementing

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a lot of questions about the garbage collection procedure, mainly when does it run, when the objects are set to an older generation, so on..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    int a = 0;
    Holder prev = new Holder(null);

    while(GC.CollectionCount(1) == 0)
    {
        int aux = GC.CollectionCount(0);
        if(aux > a){
            a = aux; 
            ++j; 
            Console.WriteLine((i+1));
         }
        ++i;
        Holder h = new Holder(prev);
        Console.WriteLine(GC.GetGeneration(prev));
        prev = h;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the number of objects in the gen1.
Why does `j = 1;` ?? the GC only runs once on the gen0 (to leave the while shouldn't it at least run 2 times)?

**[EDIT]** 
by adding this after the while breaks, i got very confused

`Console.WriteLine("#gc0 = "+GC.CollectionCount(0)); --> 2
 Console.WriteLine("#gc1 = "+GC.CollectionCount(1)); --> 1
 Console.WriteLine("#objs = "+ i);
 Console.ReadLine();`

how come the GC.CollectionCount(0) be only 2? I´ve been reading Richter clr via c# and he said this

> the objects in generation 1 are examined
>   only when generation 1 reaches its budget, which usually requires several garbage collections of
>   generation 0.

**[EDIT]**

but at the same time, if the gc sees that all the object's survived, it grows g0 limit, maybe the reason for only 2 gc's on g0?

Answer (score 1):

How about we spice things up with a bit of randomness like this:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            int i = 0, j = 0;
            int a = 0;
            Holder prev = new Holder(null);
            Holder prev2 = new Holder(null);

            while (GC.CollectionCount(1) == 0)
            {
                int aux = GC.CollectionCount(0);
                if (aux > a)
                {
                    a = aux;
                    ++j;
                    Console.WriteLine((i + 1));
                }
                ++i;
                var flag = random.Next(1) == 1;
                Holder h = new Holder(flag ? prev : prev2);
                Console.WriteLine("Prev: " + GC.GetGeneration(prev));
                Console.WriteLine("Prev2: " + GC.GetGeneration(prev2));

                if (flag)
                {
                    prev = h;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev2 = h;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Holder
    {
        private Holder holder;

        public Holder(Holder o)
        {
            holder = o;
        }
    }
```

The code sample you've provided was so simple that the CLR knew there was not point in moving your `prev` item to another generation. 
It usage was simple and I think that the runtime had it optimized it to live on G0 only.

Adding a more complex logic breaks the runtime's optimizations and now one of `prev` or `prev1` will go on the G1 depending on which of the objects was used less frequently (don't know the exact mechanics here).

You can try adding instead of `prev` and `prev2` an `prevs` array and do a random there on the index and you can better see how the array elements will advance the generations.